# How run multiple servers with Gulp?

Tags: gulp

I am trying to run Gulp for open 2 servers both with livereload at the same time. Is it possible? 
My code:
http://pastebin.com/B6GAuvWB

Comment: Please could you add the relevant code into your question text?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can:

[Multiple-Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect#multiple-server)

But relating to your code, you are already starting two servers at the same time.

Comment: if you see the code i posted i used the same example

Answer (score 0):

You would need 2 different ports for livereload
https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload/blob/master/examples/custom-port.js

Comment: Not for the livereload servers. The default port for livereload is 35729. If you put this in your browser you will see what the livereload server is serving. http://localhost:35729/